# Modal window back to Android device showing 'Web page not available'

Tags: javascript, android, trigger.io

I'm having an issue with the Modal window in trigger.io. For example, if I use the below code:

```
$('#oauth_login').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    forge.tabs.open('http://' + oAuth_path + '/', true, function (data) {
        forge.logging.log(data)

    });
});
```

The script at 'oAuth_path' on completion redirects the user to 'forge:///' by executing the following command

```
<?php
    header('LOCATION: forge:///');
?>
```

On an IOS device that returns me back to the mobile application; on and Android device I see an error page which states 'Web page not available'... 'The webpage at content://io.trigger.forge'... 'Might be temporaily down or'...

Is this a bug with Trigger on Android? I've tested on Samsung Note 1 and Android Emulator.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also close the modal view automatically as soon as a specific pattern is hit within the view.

```
var returnUrl = "https://mydomain.com/loginFinished";
var url = "https://mydomain.com/loginDialog?returnUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(returnUrl);

window.forge.tabs.openWithOptions({
  url: url,
  pattern: returnUrl+'*'
}, function(response) {
  // success
}, function() {
  // error
});
```

Within you authentication process (at `https://mydomain.com/loginDialog`) you should redirect the user to the `returnUrl` on success. This will automatically close the modal view.

On some older Android devices I observed that the pattern won't be hit even if it should. I recommend to have a simple page at `https://mydomain.com/loginFinished` that says something like *"Authentication finished. Please close this tab."* to have a fallback for this issue.

You can find more information about [match patterns in modal views](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/features/modal.html#match-pattern) at the Trigger.io documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to redirect the user back to a specific page, for example `forge:///index.html`.